# How to render HTML component full page in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently using vanilla JS + HTML to render a different HTML file, (**loadscreen.html**) in **index.html** in a **div** element. The problem is that when the HTML is loaded, it's supposed to be full page, but only renders a tiny portion.  Here's what it's supposed to look like:
[image]

But here's what the page actually renders:

[image]

Here is my JS+HTML code below for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    var state = "turnOn";
    const setState = setTimeout(changeStateToLoaded, 10000);

    var render = function (template, node) {
        if (!node) return;
        node.innerHTML = (typeof template === 'function' ? template() : template);
    };

    var renderTemplate = function () {
        if (state === 'turnOn') {
            template = '<object type="text/html" data="loadingscreen.html" ></object>';;
        }
        else if(state === 'loaded') {
            template = '<h1>Hello world!</h1>';
        }
        return template;
    };

    function changeStateToLoaded() {
        state = "loaded";
        render(renderTemplate, document.querySelector('#main'));
    }

    render(renderTemplate, document.querySelector('#main'));
</script>
```

This is the code for loadingscreen.html (the HTML for the loading screen):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loading_screen/loadingscreen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="window">
            <div class="logo">
                <p class="top">Microsoft</p>
                <p class="mid">Windows<span>97</span></p>
                <p class="bottom">Professional</p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS for loadingscreen.html:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,700');
body{
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
.window{
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)

}
.container{
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
.box{
  width: 9px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2838c7 0%,#5979ef 17%,#869ef3 32%,#869ef3 45%,#5979ef 59%,#2838c7 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  animation: loader 2s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.logo{
  width: 220px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.logo p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 16px;
}
.top:after{
  content:"\00a9";
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.mid{
  font-size: 46px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 36px;
}
.mid span{
  font-size: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #FF6821;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
.logo .bottom{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;

}
@keyframes loader{
  0%{
    transform: translate(-30px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(150px);
  }
}
```

How would I make the loadingscreen.html page render full page in the code?

Comment: It seems like you need to specify a `width` and `height` for your [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)

Comment: I don't see anything that assigns height or width to `.main` anywhere...